# How can I see which bosses I haven't beat with a specific weapon yet?

Tags: hades

You get some special drops for beating a boss the first time with a particular weapon. Those are kinda useful, so I thought I might want to farm a few more of them. What I can't seem to find is a way to see which bosses I have beat with which weapon already.

Is there a way to figure out which weapon/boss combinations I haven't completed yet that will drop interesting loot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you haven't unlocked the *Pact of Punisment* yet, because it has a nice interface that tells you which rewards you've earned with your current weapon. The *Pact* does unlock at certain point of normal gameplay, but I can see why it might take a while to get it open.
In [Hell Mode](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Hell_Mode), the Pact is available from the start.

[image: Pact of punishment for rail]

It also does other things, but let's not go into those to avoid spoilers. The screenshot, from the [Hades Wiki -page](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Pact_of_Punishment), is also cropped to avoid spoilers.

As for before then, to quote our good friend [Skelly](https://youtu.be/LnBvXqHo8dw?t=2940):

> I don't know, there's always the invention of writing stuff down? You'll figure something out.